# Retrieve children of child in realtime database firebase with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to retreive some data from realtime database firebase and display it on the screen. I have implemented a function snapshotToArray to convert Json to array.
I have the feedback collection and I want to retreive all the children of JAHC9F.. to display the contents of if child (inside new ,task1,task4 and new)

Here in my case, I can see only two objets for two children but I cant see the contents of each feedback

[image]

*user.uid is equal to J4HC9FgMM.. in this case

```
 componentDidMount=async()=>{
   const feedbacks=await firebase.database().ref("Feedback").child(user.uid).once('value');
   const feedbackArray=snapshotToArray(feedbacks);
   this.props.loadFeedbacks(feedbackArray);
 }



renderItemFeedback = (item, index) => {
 return (
   <View>
     <Text>{item.name}</Text>
     <View>
         <NetworkImage
           source={{ uri: item.ImageFeedback }}
         />
     </View>

     <View>
       <Text>{item.countLike}</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
 );
};
render() {
 return (
   <CustomBackground>
     <ScrollView>
       <View>
         <FlatList
           data={this.props.feedbacks.feedbacks}
           renderItem={({ item }, index) =>
             this.renderItemFeedback(item, index)
           }
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         />
       </View>

     </ScrollView>
   </CustomBackground>
 );
}
}
```

Here the implementation of snapshotToArray function :

```
export const snapshotToArray= snapshot=>{
    let returnArr=[]

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        let item=childSnapshot.val()
        item.key=childSnapshot.key

        returnArr.push(item)
    });

    return returnArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see two items in the array, that is working as expected as there are two child nodes under `J4HC9FgMM..` in the screenshot.

If you want to show the child nodes of each child node (so the nodes with names `New`, `Task1`, etc), then you need two nested loops:

```
export const snapshotToArray= snapshot=>{
    let returnArr=[]

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        childSnapshot.forEach(grandchildSnapshot => {
            let item=grandchildSnapshot.val()
            item.key=grandchildSnapshot.key

            returnArr.push(item)
        })
    });

    return returnArr;
}
```